# angular directive not running during application startup

Tags: angularjs, directive

I've added angularjs directive, but it not running during app startup.
No debug is printed in debug console.

html code:

```
   <li has-role="ROLE_ADMIN" class="dropdown pointer"></li>
```

angularjs directive:

```
    angular.module('myApp').directive('hasRole', function (){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var setVisible = function () {
                    console.log('hasAnyRole, setVisible');
                    element.removeClass('hidden');
                },
                setHidden = function () {
                    console.log('hasAnyRole, setHidden');
                    element.addClass('hidden');
                },
                defineVisibility = function (reset) {
                    console.log('hasAnyRole, defineVisibility');
                    // other logic here...
                    setVisible();            
                },
                role = attrs.hasRole.replace(/\s+/g, '');

            //if (roles.length > 0) {
                defineVisibility(true);
            //}
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Did you property define your module using `angular.module('myApp', [])` ? The code you have show here is just a reference, but you need to add an array to initialize it.

Comment: yes, it's initialized properly in the main file.

Comment: It works fine, probably you aren't including the JS file with the directive.

Comment: I've checked includes, assigned my directive to my angular directive module and it works fine (i'm using typescipt and maybe it was problem with order when files are included in reference file). Thanks for help:)